# Navigator initial route is rendered when reopening app after Android back button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am on ScreenA. When I press Android back button, the app closes (OK). When I reopen it, the "initial route" of my Root navigator gets mounted (SplashScreen), which actually runs Bootstrap and bad things happen. If I am on ScreenA and just press Android home button, and go back, it's OK - I am still on ScreenA and initial route is not rendered. Any idea why initial route is being mounted after an Android hardware press?

Below my config:

```
export const MyRootStack = createStackNavigator<IRootStackNavigationParamList>();
function RootStackScreen() {
    return (
        <MyRootStack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={RouteNames.SplashScreen}
            headerMode={"none"}
        >
            <MyRootStack.Screen
                name={RouteNames.SplashScreen}
                component={RootSplashScreen}
            />
            <MyRootStack.Screen
                name={RouteNames.LoginScreen}
                component={LoginScreen}
                options={{ cardStyleInterpolator: forFade }}
            />
            <MyRootStack.Screen
                name={RouteNames.ScreenA}
                component={ScreenAStack}
                options={{ cardStyleInterpolator: forFade }}
            />
        </MyRootStack.Navigator>);
}

export const MyNavigationContainer: React.FC<{}> = RootStackScreen; // typing as React.FC to be able to render as JSX
```

Any suggestions much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: The initial route renders when you open the app, what else do you expect would happen?

Comment: When I used react-navigation v3, closing the app by pressing the back button worked like pressing the home button. (I believe). Or should Android back behave like killing the app and reopening? Thanks!

Comment: Pressing back button closes the app. You can check other Android apps on your phone and see that pressing back button doesn't behave the same as pressing home button.